# Power BI Timestamp Refresh for Dataset AND Report

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report with a live connection to a Power BI Dataset. The dataset contains a query that uses `DateTime.LocalNow()` to timestamp the most recent refresh. So far so good. My report consumer can now know at at any time how up to date the dataset is.

However, I'd like to also include a timestamp for the last **report** refresh. The problem is everything under Get Data is greyed out:

[image]

I understand this is because my model resides in the dataset, but is there any way to expand on the existing data model from within my report in order to include second refresh query? If not, can anyone think of a way to capture both the last dataset refresh and the last report refresh?

Comment: Do you mean the last time your report design was modified?  If you want to display the current time when the report is run you can use a (local or remote) measure like `CurrentTime = NOW()`

Comment: No, not report modification. It should timestamp when the report consumer clicks refresh. A measure wouldn't work, because it would update whenever the user has any kind of interaction (filter, page navigation, etc.) with the report. What I need is a blank query, but everything is greyed out.

Comment: But it’s live connect.  There is no local data model to refresh.